# Correct syntax to call elements in an array

Tags: arrays, syntax

I'm learning, but I am having a hard time finding the correct syntax to get an element inside an array that's pretty dense.  Here's a snippet:

```
var data = {
    "presidents": {
        "date": "2014-11-03",
        "president": [
            {
                "number": 1,
                "name": "George Washington",
                "date": "1732-02-22",
                "took_office": "1789-04-30",
                "left_office": "1797-03-04",
                "party": "no party",
                "term": [
                    {
                        "number": 1,
                        "vice_president": "John Adams"
                    },
                    {
                        "number": 2,
                        "vice_president": "John Adams"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "number": 2,
                "name": "John Adams",
                "date": "1735-10-30",
                "took_office": "1797-03-04",
                "left_office": "1801-03-04",
                "party": "Federalist",
                "term": {
                    "number": 3,
                    "vice_president": "Thomas Jefferson"
                }
            }.....
```

So if I wanted to search through this by Presidents' Name, I first wanted to understand how to assign a single element.  My first thought was this:

```
x= president.presidents[1].name
```

But that's not correct. How should this syntax go?  Thanks, as I said, I'm still learning.

Comment: Shall we assume that this is Javascript?

Comment: Could you please format it? Its hard to read

Comment: Sorry, yes, Javascript.  Thanks David

Comment: In general, when you show what you tried and state that it isn't correct, please also explain *why* it isn't correct. What did you expect and what did you get instead?

Answer (score 1):

`data` is an object that contains a field called `presidents`. Which is plural - making me think it should be an array of presidents.  It's not.  It's an ***object*** that contains a field called `president` (*which is an array??*). `president[]` is an object that contains a field called `name`.

x = data.presidents.president[0].name

Comment: Thanks, this was what kept tripping me up as I tried to visualize the structure.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is you would process this using JS so can be done like this

```
$.each(data.presidents, function(indd,obj){
    if(indd == "president"){
      $.each(obj , function(i,val){
         console.log(i+"---"+val['name'])
    })}
})
```

You can check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pkmdtvs1/10/)

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense.  I kept stumbling upon the rather unique way the data was given to us.